# read data from PL and show plot in Django

Tags: python, django, pandas, postgresql, plot

I am very beginner in Django and Python. I have table in Postgres as below:

```
ID |Date          |Name    |Price
1  , 2011.01.01   , A      , 100
2  , 2011.01.02   , A      , 200
3  , 2011.01.03   , A      , 150
```

and I want to read this table in Django and show plot for 'A' company based on the date, actually in my plot X is Date and Y is Price value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read data, then you have to query like this:-

```
TableName.objects.filter(name='A') # get all the data where the name = 'A'
```

And if you want to put the filter of date, you can also pass "date" in the filter of query.